# Loading images only one time per spring webapp

Tags: java, spring, singleton, javabeans, startup

I need to load a bunch of images into my Spring webapp. For performance reasons this should only be done after starting the webapp. The images should be saved in a singleton to access from multiple users, sessions etc

I already build a Java Bean with an initalizer that loads the images, in my controller I inject this bean and get the images. Works, but injecting isn't the right thing for this.

**How can I build a singleton bean to hold the images and only load the images one time per webapp?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) built-in [web caching](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching)? Just add it to your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>pageCachingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>pageCachingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And configure `SimplePageCachingFilter` cache in your `ehcache.xml`:

```
<cache name="SimplePageCachingFilter"
       maxElementsInMemory="1000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="31536000"
       timeToLiveSeconds="31536000"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
       statistics="true"
        />
```

EhCache will now intercept all client-side requests for static resources, read them once, put them in cache and return to the user. To make it even better, it will even add HTTP `Expiry` headeres so the client won't call you again for the same resource.

Isn't this approach better compared to manually-written loading and caching in a singleton?

Comment: sounds great and for using ist its only neccessary to configure the filter? nice. Where to put the `ehcache.xml` ? Same as path as web.xml? Never used ehcache before.

Comment: You need to place `ehcache.xml` in the root of your `CLASSPATH` (e.g. `/src/main/resources`). They have very extensive documentation, check it out to see other features.

Comment: I configured everything as you said, added the `<ehcache>`-Tags to `ehcache.xml` and include ehcache via maven-snippet from the docs. But tomcat can't start the app, `FAIL - Application at context path /webapp could not be started`, looks like tomcat cant resolve the web xml the right way.. Couldn't find a log-entry with details yet. Any ideas, what caused that?

Comment: Hard to say, you really have to find the exact exception. It can be anything: `ehcache.xml` or `web.xml` not found/malformed, `ehcache.jar` not found on the CLASSPATH. Look at your application log, I am using the exact same config with great success.

Comment: Found it in `localhost.log` --> `SEVERE: Exception starting filter pageCachingFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter
` the web.xml looks like yours, jar included in `WEB-INF/lib` are `slf4j.jar`, `ehcache-core.jar` and `ehcache-terracotta.jar`

Comment: You also need `ehcache-web.jar` on your CLASSPATH, the error message points to a class from this JAR...